# Scatter Plot: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror, scatter

Being `E` a random distribution (not relevant to the question) and having two lists called `t` and `u`:

```
t = []
u = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,1, num_round), num_cifre).tolist()
for val in u:
  t.append(E.ppf(u))
```

They should be of the same size, in fact doing: `print(len(u) == len(t))` returns `True`

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with them using:

```
plt.scatter(u,t)
plt.show()
```

But when I execute the code this error comes out:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Answer (score 1):

ppf() returns an array not a single value. So you have a list of values and a list of arrays that causes the issue, I guess